# Should i create a new UnitOfWork in every method or have a class instance?

Tags: model-view-controller, unit-of-work

In my controller class, should i create a new instance of UnitOfWork in every method or should i have a class instance that the methods access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the way controllers behave with dispose, my conclusion is that it doesnt matter. But i think a class instance looks cleaner since the class gets disposed after every GET/POST.